# Generic method overriding a generic method of its base

Tags: java, generics

Suppose

- We have two classes: `A` and `B`, which `B` extends `A`.
- We have two *wrapper* classes for them: `AWrapper` and `BWrapper` which `BWrapper` extends `AWrapper`.

AWrapper.java

```
class AWrapper {
    public <T extends A> void wrap(T obj) {}
}
```

BWrapper.java

```
class BWrapper extends AWrapper {
    @Override // This doesn't override! why?
    public <T extends B> void wrap(T obj) {}
}
```

Question: Why can't we in BWrapper.java *generically* override `wrap` method?

Comment: I think because in AWrapper T is of Type A and in BWrapper T is of Type B I believe B should extend A

Comment: @GilGoldzweig It does, but still not overriding.

Comment: What java version are you running?

Comment: Because `AWrapper`'s `wrap` returns a subtype of `A`, and so must overriding subclasses. How does `B extend A` in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two generic parameters (both named `T`) are unrelated, since they are defined at the method level. Therefore your `BWrapper` method doesn't override the `AWrapper` method of the same name.

You can define them at the class level:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

class AWrapper<T extends A> {
    public void wrap(T obj) {}
}

class BWrapper<T extends B> extends AWrapper<T> {
    @Override
    public void wrap(T obj) {}
}
```